# how to build arm64-v8a folder without arm64 .so file with .apk?

Tags: android, android-ndk

i have prebuilt .so libraries but i can not have  arm64-v8a .so file. According to Google new Policies 64-bit architectures is necessary for uploading .apk in play store. i can add

```
 ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64','mips'
```

in gradle.build but in my .apk  arm64-v8a folder in not included. i manually add  arm64-v8a folder in jniLibs folder with dome file but in .apk  arm64-v8a folder in not included how can i include arm64-v8a folder in my .apk with out arm64-v8a .so Librairie.

Comment: The point of the Google Play restriction is to force you to make a 64-bit build of your native code. You need to create a 64-bit library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify prebuild libs in your `Android.mk` file from the `jni` folder, here is an example:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := your-module
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := your-module

ifeq (arm64-v8a,$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/your-module-arm64.a
endif

ifeq (armeabi-v7a,$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/your-module-arm.a
endif

ifeq (x86,$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/your-module-x86.a
endif

ifeq (x86_64,$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/your-module-x86_64.a
endif

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```